# How to create key of object in json with jq?

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have a json file as belows:

```
{
  "HealthCheckPath": "/",
  "HealthCheckIntervalSeconds": 30
}
```

I wanna create a key with Test name. My desired result:

```
"Test": {
      "HealthCheckPath": "/",
      "HealthCheckIntervalSeconds": 30
}
```

I want to using jq option with bash or other way via bash shell.

Comment: What did you try? This seems to be like a 'Give me the code' question

Comment: the JSON expected output isn't even a valid JSON snippet. Check it in [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run below to get desired output:

```
jq '{ "Test" : .}' file.json
```